# "array" в ms sql (for xml)

Tags: массивы, sql-server, xml, xquery

Всем здравствуйте!
Начал познавать язык запросов ms-sql и в качестве поставленного себе задания пытаюсь передать на сторону xml, содержащую определенные данные.

Проблема возникла в том, что возможности вывода одного бандла данных - ограниченны строкой (в моём случае), в результате я не могу получить необходимый мне результат просто использовав Join на паре таблиц.. Возможно мне поможет подзапрос с  for xml в одно поле для того чтобы сформировать своеобразный "массив" в рамках одного поля для вывода красивой общей картинки в результате for xml - возможно, стоит собирать данные отдельно блоками в поля или есть неизвестный мне способ собрать так как я бы хотел - решил спросить у знатоков.

Ниже привожу входные данные, результат и желаемый результат. Спасибо :/

```
create table #pers (id_pers int , N varchar (20), S varchar (55), comment varchar (max))
create table #persinfo (id_persinfo int, id_pers int, number varchar(20))


insert into #pers values (1,'Alex','Ground','StackOvfw'),(2,'Dmitry','Terra','StackOvfw'),(3,'Dmitry','Land','StackOvfw'),(4,'Maximus','Earth','StackOvfw'),(5,'Daniel','Soil','StackOvfw')
insert into #persinfo values (1,1,'8-800-555-35-35'),(2,1,'8-801-555-35-35'), (3,2,'8-999-999-99-99')


select 
p.id_pers as [Person/URN_ID],
p.N as [Person/Name],
p.S as [Person/Surname],
pinfo.id_persinfo as [Person/Person_Infos/URN_ID],
pinfo.id_persinfo as [Person_INFOs/Person_info/URN_ID],
pinfo.number as [Person_INFOs/Person_info/TNumber]
from #pers p 
join #persinfo pinfo on p.id_pers = pinfo.id_pers
where p.id_pers = 1
for xml path('Bundle'), root ('Persons')
```

Как результат получаю 2 позиции (т.к. столько отдаёт селект, но хотелось бы получать 1)

Результат:

```
<Persons>
  <Bundle>
    <Person>
      <URN_ID>1</URN_ID>
      <Name>Alex</Name>
      <Surname>Ground</Surname>
      <Person_Infos>
        <URN_ID>1</URN_ID>
      </Person_Infos>
    </Person>
    <Person_INFOs>
      <Person_info>
        <URN_ID>1</URN_ID>
        <TNumber>8-800-555-35-35</TNumber>
      </Person_info>
    </Person_INFOs>
  </Bundle>
  <Bundle>
    <Person>
      <URN_ID>1</URN_ID>
      <Name>Alex</Name>
      <Surname>Ground</Surname>
      <Person_Infos>
        <URN_ID>2</URN_ID>
      </Person_Infos>
    </Person>
    <Person_INFOs>
      <Person_info>
        <URN_ID>2</URN_ID>
        <TNumber>8-801-555-35-35</TNumber>
      </Person_info>
    </Person_INFOs>
  </Bundle>
</Persons>
```

Желаемый же результат таков:

```
<Persons>
  <Bundle>
    <Person>
      <URN_ID>1</URN_ID>
      <Name>Alex</Name>
      <Surname>Ground</Surname>
      <Person_Infos>
        <URN_ID>1</URN_ID>
        <URN_ID>2</URN_ID>
      </Person_Infos>
    </Person>
    <Person_INFOs>
      <Person_info>
        <URN_ID>1</URN_ID>
        <TNumber>8-800-555-35-35</TNumber>
      </Person_info>
      <Person_info>
        <URN_ID>2</URN_ID>
        <TNumber>8-801-555-35-35</TNumber>
      </Person_info>
    </Person_INFOs>
  </Bundle>
</Persons>
```

Answer (score 2):

Похоже на решение Петрова, но более чистый XML метод. И из-за этого имена элементов XML более просты.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @pers TABLE (id_pers INT, N VARCHAR(20), S VARCHAR(55), comment VARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @persinfo TABLE (id_persinfo INT, id_pers INT, number VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @pers
VALUES
(1, 'Alex', 'Ground', 'StackOvfw'),
(2, 'Dmitry', 'Terra', 'StackOvfw'),
(3, 'Dmitry', 'Land', 'StackOvfw'),
(4, 'Maximus', 'Earth', 'StackOvfw'),
(5, 'Daniel', 'Soil', 'StackOvfw');
INSERT INTO @persinfo
VALUES
(1, 1, '8-800-555-35-35'),
(2, 1, '8-801-555-35-35'),
(3, 2, '8-999-999-99-99');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT 
(
SELECT p.id_pers as [URN_ID],
    p.N as [Name],
    p.S as [Surname],
    (
        SELECT pinfo.id_persInfo as [URN_ID]            
        FROM @persinfo AS pinfo
        WHERE p.id_pers = pinfo.id_pers
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Person_Infos')
    )
    FROM @pers AS p
    WHERE p.id_pers = per.id_pers
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Person')
    ),
    (
        SELECT pinfo.id_persinfo as [URN_ID],
            pinfo.number as [TNumber]
        FROM @persinfo AS pinfo
        WHERE per.id_pers = pinfo.id_pers
        FOR XML PATH('Person_info'), TYPE, ROOT('Person_INFOs')
    )
FROM @pers AS per
WHERE per.id_pers = 1
FOR XML PATH('Bundle'), TYPE, ROOT('Persons');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    p.id_pers as [Person/URN_ID],
    p.N as [Person/Name],
    p.S as [Person/Surname],
    (
        select pinfo.id_persInfo as [URN_ID]            
        from #persinfo pinfo
        where p.id_pers = pinfo.id_pers
        for xml path(''), type
    ) as [Person/Person_Infos],
    (
        select
            pinfo.id_persinfo as [Person_info/URN_ID],
            pinfo.number as [Person_info/TNumber]
        from #persinfo pinfo
        where p.id_pers = pinfo.id_pers
        for xml path(''), type
    ) as [Person_INFOs]
from #pers p
where p.id_pers = 1
for xml path('Bundle'), root('Persons')
```

Не уверен в эффективности запроса, но выдаёт желаемый результат.